# ERROR:colcon.colcon_core.shell:Exception in shell extension 'sh'

Tags: ros2

I follow the instructions in [ROS2 Foxy Ubuntu source build](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html#build-the-code-in-the-workspace), but it fails at [Build the code in the workspace](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html#build-the-code-in-the-workspace) when I run the command:

```bash
colcon build --symlink-install
```

Result in:

```bash
Starting >>> ament_package
Starting >>> ament_lint                       
Starting >>> gtest_vendor
Starting >>> fastcdr
Finished <<< gtest_vendor [3.42s]                             
Starting >>> gmock_vendor                                     
Finished <<< gmock_vendor [1.03s]                             
Starting >>> ament_cppcheck
Finished <<< ament_lint [5.03s]                               
Starting >>> ament_flake8
Finished <<< ament_package [5.26s]                            
Starting >>> ament_cmake_core
Finished <<< ament_cppcheck [2.12s]                            
Starting >>> cyclonedds
Finished <<< ament_flake8 [2.43s]                              
Starting >>> ament_pep257
Finished <<< ament_cmake_core [3.80s]                          
Starting >>> ament_cmake_libraries                             
[14.389s] ERROR:colcon.colcon_core.shell:Exception in shell extension 'sh': Expected ['.', '/home/john/ros2_foxy/build/ament_cmake_libraries/colcon_command_prefix_build.sh', '&&', 'env'] to pass: /bin/sh: 3: /home/john/ros2_foxy/install/ame: not foundre/share/ament_cmake_core/environment/ament_prefix_path.sh: 
/bin/sh: 2: /home/john/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_core/share/ament_cmake_core: not foundt/path.sh: 
/bin/sh: 6: /home/john/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_core/share/ament_cmake_core/environment/path.sh: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "then")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/shell/__init__.py", line 302, in get_command_environment
    return await extension.generate_command_environment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/shell/sh.py", line 154, in generate_command_environment
    env = await get_environment_variables(cmd, cwd=str(build_base))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/shell/__init__.py", line 338, in get_environment_variables
    output = await check_output(cmd, cwd=cwd, shell=shell)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/colcon_core/subprocess.py", line 128, in check_output
    assert not rc, f'Expected {args} to pass: {stderr_data}'
AssertionError: Expected ['.', '/home/john/ros2_foxy/build/ament_cmake_libraries/colcon_command_prefix_build.sh', '&&', 'env'] to pass: /bin/sh: 3: /home/john/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_core/share/ament_cmake_core/environment/ament_prefi: not found
/bin/sh: 2: /home/john/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_core/share/ament_cmake_core: not foundt/path.sh: 
/bin/sh: 6: /home/john/ros2_foxy/install/ament_cmake_core/share/ament_cmake_core/environment/path.sh: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "then")


[14.390s] ERROR:colcon.colcon_cmake.task.cmake.build:Could not find a shell extension for the command environment
Failed   <<< ament_cmake_libraries [0.13s, exited with code 1] 
Aborted  <<< fastcdr [9.74s]                                              
Aborted  <<< ament_pep257 [2.38s]                                            
Aborted  <<< cyclonedds [4.44s]                               

Summary: 7 packages finished [14.5s]
  1 package failed: ament_cmake_libraries
  3 packages aborted: ament_pep257 cyclonedds fastcdr
  300 packages not processed
```

My machine (installed in VMware) info:

```bash
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

And it is a new OS with only ROS2 Foxy being installed (follow the instructions above).

The Python is:

```bash
$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.10
```

Though I have found [Colcon fails to find 'sh' environment variables on Python 3.11.1](https://github.com/colcon/colcon-core/issues/545), it doesn't work for me. Moreover, I guess it could build ROS2 from source with Python3.8, right? So, how could I build ROS2 from source correctly?
Thank you very much for your kindly help!